# IComparer on multiple values and specific values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, icomparable

There are two Generic list of Inspectors and InspectorRates. Inspector class has object of Inspector Rate class.

[image]

RateType has three different values (0 = Not Select ,1 = Day Rate ,2 = Hourly Rates).

[image]

I want to show all inspectors with Day Type Rate first and then lowest rate. If user selects option "Hourly Rates" then list needs to be sorted by Hourly Rate and thenlowest rate. Not seleted rate will always be at the bottom.

**Example: After sorting, list content needs to be in following order (First one is ByDay and second is By Hour)**

[image]

I have create IComparer class for sorting but can't figure out how to sort list based on specific and multiple fields.

```
Public Class InspectorSort
    Implements IComparer(Of Inspector)
    Private listOrderBy As OrderBy = OrderBy.FirstName
    Private listDirection As Direction = Direction.Assending

    Public Enum OrderBy As Byte
        InspectorID = 0
        FirstName = 2   
        DayRate = 14
        HourlyRate = 15
    End Enum

    Public Enum Direction As Integer
        Assending = 1
        Decending = -1
    End Enum

    Public Sub New(ByVal mOrderBy As OrderBy, ByVal mDirection As Direction)
        listOrderBy = mOrderBy
        listDirection = mDirection
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Objects.Inspector, ByVal y As Objects.Inspector) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Objects.Inspector).Compare
        Dim value As Integer = 0

        Select Case listOrderBy
            Case OrderBy.InspectorID
                If x.InspectorID > y.InspectorID Then
                    value = 1
                ElseIf x.InspectorID < y.InspectorID Then
                    value = -1
                End If

            Case OrderBy.FirstName
                If x.FirstName.ToLower > y.FirstName.ToLower Then
                    value = 1
                ElseIf x.FirstName.ToLower < y.FirstName.ToLower Then
                    value = -1
                End If

            Case OrderBy.DayRate
                If x.DefaultRate.RateType = Rates.RateTypeEnum.Day_Rate Then
                    If x.DefaultRate.RateType = Rates.RateTypeEnum.Day_Rate And x.DefaultRate.Rate > y.DefaultRate.Rate Then
                        value = 1
                    End If

        End Select

        Return value * listDirection
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't take the time to translate to VB, but this is the based on the C# Comparer that I have created.

**UPDATED CODE**

original

```
        // RateType 0 always greatest of list
        if (x.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)        
            return 1;
```

This didn't factor in that sometimes it's the y that has the value that you want.
Added check for y and return the value accordingly

so it becomes

```
        // RateType 0 always greatest of list
        if (x.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)        
            return 1;
        else if (y.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)
            return -1;



public class InspectorDayRateComparer : IComparer<Inspector>
{
    public int Compare(Inspector x, Inspector y)
    {
        // RateType 0 always greatest of list
        if (x.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)        
            return 1;
        else if (y.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)
            return -1;

        int result = x.DefaultRate.RateType.CompareTo(y.DefaultRate.RateType);
        if (result == 0)
            result = x.DefaultRate.Rate.CompareTo(y.Defaultrate.Rate);

        return result;  
    }
}

public class InspectorHourlyRateComparer : IComparer<Inspector>
{
    public int Compare(Inspector x, Inspector y)
    {
        // RateType 0 always greatest of list
        if (x.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)        
            return 1;
        else if (y.DefaultRate.RateType == 0)
            return -1;

        // So that 1 is greater than 2 to get the order desired                 
        int result = (x.DefaultRate.RateType.CompareTo(y.DefaultRate.RateType) *-1) ;   
        if (result == 0)
            result = x.DefaultRate.Rate.CompareTo(y.Defaultrate.Rate;                           
    }
}
```

This should get you closer to where you want to get.

IComparer interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you have more element to add to the Compare, chain them using the result variable, result == 0 means that the values are the same, we must check other property for comparer.

Forcing the return value, when you have no RateType, will always make it last.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I am nearly there now. How would you apply the logic if you want to sort in 1,2,0 format. So RateType 1 on top with rates in ascending and then 2 with rates in asc and then 0

Comment: Just tested the code, see edit... should have mentionned untested sry